# Remove focus rectangle of details tag (outline:none not working)

Tags: html, css, tags

I am making some experiments with a `<details>` tag. As there is an annoying focus rectangle when I open it in Google Chrome, I tried to removed it by adding

`details:focus {
  outline: none;
}`

But that didn't work. I thought of putting the `outline: none` with a `details[open]` selector but it didn't work either. And if I tries with a button it works... Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend restructuring your code by using the `<summary>` tag. The `<summary>` tag defines a visible heading for the  element. The heading can be clicked to view/hide the details.

```
<details>  
    <summary>Details summary</summary>  
    <p>Text here</p>
</details>

summary {
  outline:none;
}
```

This will achieve the same result visually.
Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/katerynas/zhcfk5ha/1/

Comment: Good answer. According to the documentation here: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interactive-elements.html#the-details-element , if there is no child summaries the user agent will provide it's own. However, you don't have styling access to it, so it's best to include one in this circumstance if your goal is to customize it.

Comment: Didn't think of adding outline:none to the summary... worked indeed!